# Why do hidden fields produce hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, hidden-fields

My Hidden Field:

```
- @calc.results.each do |k, v|
  = hidden_field :calc_result, :value => "#{k[:total_interest]}"
```

Which returns :

```
"calc_result"=>
{"value214.14"=>"",
...
```

How can I write the hidden_field so that it produces :

```
"value" => "214.14"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass :value, just say this:

`= hidden_field_tag :calc_result, "#{k[:total_interest]}"`

That should get you what you want.

Comment: Hmm.. so strange. That returns this in html => `<input type="hidden" name="calc_result[39.12]" id="calc_result_39.12">` and this in rails `"117.68"=>"",`

Comment: See the update I just posted.  Since this isn't generated inside a form object, you need to use hidden_field_tag.

Answer (score 1):

By using `hidden_field`, the name attribute is interpreted from the field name (in this case `:calc_result`.

If `value` is not a field in the model, you could use `hidden_field_tag` instead.

```
= hidden_field_tag "value", k[:total_interest]}
```